# Dataproc custom image: Cannot complete creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

For a project, I have to create a Dataproc cluster that has one of the outdated versions (for example, 1.3.94-debian10) that contain the vulnerabilities in Apache Log4j 2 utility. The goal is to get the alert related (`DATAPROC_IMAGE_OUTDATED`), in order to check how SCC works (it is just for a test environment).

I tried to run the command `gcloud dataproc clusters create dataproc-cluster --region=us-east1 --image-version=1.3.94-debian10` but got the following message `ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Selected software image version 1.3.94-debian10 is vulnerable to remote code execution due to a log4j vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228) and cannot be used to create new clusters. Please upgrade to image versions >=1.3.95, >=1.4.77, >=1.5.53, or >=2.0.27. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/recreate-cluster`, which makes sense, in order to protect the cluster.

I did some research and discovered that I will have to create a custom image with said version and generate the cluster from that. The thing is, I have tried to read the documentation or find some tutorial, but I still can't understand how to start or to run the file `generate_custom_image.py`, for example, since I am not confortable with cloud shell (I prefer the console).

Can someone help? Thank you

Comment: Custom image creation doesn't have web UI, it only provides command line interface, you can run it in any shell environment with `python generate_custom_image.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these doc:

- https://medium.com/critigenopensource/how-to-run-java-11-on-your-gcp-dataproc-spark-cluster-8472f5fbaaf8
- https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images

I used this script for installing Java 17:

```
echo "Installing custom packages..."
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt install -y openjdk-17-jdk
sudo apt install -y openjdk-17-jre
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"export
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
echo $JAVA_HOME
java -version
echo "Successfully installed java 11 packages."
```

Open Cloud Shell and run this:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/custom-images
cd custom-images
```

Then create a files java_17.sh

```
nano java_17.sh
```

Paste the above sh script and save it - option+o and then exit option+x
Run `cat java_17.sh` to view the content of script.

Now run the below python script and **customise it accordingly**:

```
python3 generate_custom_image.py --image-name "custom-debian-java17" --dataproc-version "2.1-debian11" --customization-script java_17.sh --zone "us-west1-b" --disk-size "40" --gcs-bucket "gs://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/custom-image" --subnetwork "projects/xxxx/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/xxxxxxxx" --service-account "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```